# UISwtich off/on - image won't appear

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch outlet on my toolbar, and I've set off/on-images in the interface builder, but they don't appear when I run the app.

Is there anything extraordinary you have to do to make these images appear instead of the standard switch-look? I really thought this would be a straight forward process.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there are no off-on images. You can't customize the look of a UISwitch except for tint colors. The off-on images were withdrawn back in iOS 7.

(So the extraordinary thing you would have to do would be to run on iOS 6!)

Comment: Wow, that's just weird, it seems like a really useful function. Do you have any other suggestions on how to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Weird, yes. This feature appeared in iOS 6 and went away again in iOS 7. - There are plenty of third-party libraries that give you something that _looks_ more or less like a UISwitch but is customizable. Do a search, I'm sure you'll find something.